# android animation make visible an item that i make invisible by code already

Tags: java, android, animation

i have a button that is set to disappear at the activity start by this code:

```
againbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

inside another button i run this animation for my invisible button:

```
Animation anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.againbtnonanim);
anim3.setFillAfter(true);
againbtn.startAnimation(anim3);
```

when this animation runs, my invisible button appears!!! why is this so? I dont want this!what I want is first I make it visible and then it runs my animation, like this:

```
againbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
Animation anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.againbtnonanim);
anim3.setFillAfter(true);
againbtn.startAnimation(anim3);
```

but it doesn't work. 
My button appears without againbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); code and my animation is making it Invisible with this code: againbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);, but this doesnt work as well.

with this siuation, when the button is invisible by an animation, it's click listener still works in that area!!! can someone please help me out?

Comment: set button enable property to false along with invisible.

Comment: @Jibran Khan: i do this , but my main problem is there still. the disappeared button's space still there and just i disabled it! i dont want it. i want the button gone and makes free the space!

Comment: show your `againbtnonanim` file

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:visibility="gone"` when you are done with the button click. It will be completely removed. The space used by that button can be reused. When you just say `invisible` you don't remove the button you just make it invisible. Its still there consuming that space.

also with your current code you could just use android `your_button_name.setEnabled(false)` so that the onclick does not work.

Comment: i do this , but my main problem is there still. the disappeared button's space still there and just i disabled it! i dont want it. i want the button gone and makes free the space!

Comment: I have mentioned there android:visibility="gone" will remove the button completely. Your space will be free after the removal. use android:visibility="gone"

Comment: Then simply replace the View.INVISIBLE with View.GONE

Comment: i do it but still my button's space not removed :(

Comment: exactly. that's my point. View.GONE in the activity or android:visibility="gone" in the xml will solve the problem.

Comment: space has to be removed. you are going wrong somewhere. share your xml file.

Comment: you know, after my animation i have to write this code? :
againbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

right? but this doesn't solve my problem!!!

Comment: write that line in your onclick method of the button after button operation is done.

Comment: this is my complete code, it doesn't work  :( please help me.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5657364/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27160/discussion-between-abhi-is-learning-android-and-farhad-shirzad)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   againbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```